# Can you change the <html> lang="" attribute after page load with JavaScript or does the browser ignore changes?

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization

I have a system I'm working in that does not dynamically set the lang="" attribute in the  tag on the pages it serves. Once the page loads, I can infer the page language and set lang="" to the correct language tag.

I don't need help with the Javascript to do this alternation, what I'm uncertain about is if the browser only reads the lang attribute on initial render, or if it's something that can be updated at will.

Are there any problems with setting the lang attribute via JavaScript after page load?

Comment: Most robots / crawlers parsing your pages will not run JS, so changing it later seems kind of pointless.

Comment: I thought about that, luckily I'm not worried about Crawlers. More interested about the potential impact the attribute might have on the native formatting (e.g. number decimal and separator) used in form fields.